# Using TeraTerm to send a file, transfer rate, time

Tags: time, performance, modem

I'm using TeraTerm to transfer a file through a dial up connection, for this I will use ttl scripts in both ends to automatize it. I would like to measure the time it takes to transfer the file, or the transfer rate... but I don't know how to do it? Does anyone have any idea? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

gettime will give you the time but you need to get the correct times to properly calculate the throughput. You need to gettime on the side that is sending the data at the start of the sending. Then gettime on the side receiving at the end of the receive. Send the gettime from one of the sides to the other and do the math. Keep in mind each machine must have synchronized time. So each should be using a time server.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can call [gettime](http://ttssh2.sourceforge.jp/manual/en/macro/command/gettime.html) before and after and then use those two points to calculate the time used.